# Why is this .htaccess file not presenting files that exist?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple .htaccess file that is intended to redirect any request to index.php, if the file does not exist and is not a directory.

[ Before Suggested Modifications ]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#REWRITE RULES
#---------------------

#RULE COMPLETEREWRITE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.* index.php

</IfModule>
```

[ After Suggested Modifications ]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#REWRITE RULES
#---------------------

#RULE COMPLETEREWRITE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

( No change between htaccess modifications )

At the moment, it redirects to index.php regardless of whether or not the file exists. Can anyone explain why this might be?

It seems like a silly question - but I've done a bit of research and have turned up little.

This is running in Apache 2.4 under Ubuntu with mod_rewrite enabled, obviously I hope.

Case Scenario:

The file at '/resource/img/panoramas/1.png' Exists. Verified on my VM filesystem through the local file browser, SSH, and FTP.

Before implementing the htaccess file, this file was accessible remotely. I have a cached version to prove it.

After implementing the htaccess file, any attempt to hit this path returns index.php.

===============

The core for my CMS contains methods that create headers when a rewrite has been used. If I land on index.php itself, I do not flag a rewrite ( as expected ). If I hit any other path under this directory, I end up at index.php with a rewrite flag ( partially expected ). This should Not be the case if the file exists, but still occurs contrary to expectation.

It may also pay to note that this htaccess file was generated automatically from a web.config (IIS) file, and under IIS, these rules and my CMS both work entirely as expected.

Finally ( contrary to best practices ), the entire directory is chmod'ed to 777, so as to eliminate the possibility of the file being inaccessible.

Comment: Explain directory layout, document root and request paths, enable the rewrite log flag. Instead consider FallBackResource on Apache 2.4. The IfModule wrapping is usually pointless.

Comment: make sure that those rules are actually being tested. remember that apache can have overrides in MANY places, including other .htaccess files in higher directories that can be causing THESE rules to be bypassed completely.

Comment: How are you testing that it is routing to `index.php` even for existing file?

Comment: I've written a check to determine whether or not a rewrite occurred, and get a working rewrite when I hand it a file that I know exists. For instance; '/resource/image/panoramas/1.png' Exists from my root - and prior to creating this htaccess file, I could access it. I have the cached original to prove it. When I hit that .png file now with the htaccess file in place, I am redirected to my index.php file, and do not get an image back.

Comment: My index.php file also writes back a header saying that it detected a rewrite; further indicating the above.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 - so no `.htaccess` files any any child directory?

Comment: Try `RewriteLogLevel 3` to see what happens...

Comment: You need to enable `RewriteLog` and attach that output in question for request to image file.

Comment: I presume RewriteLog is another htaccess parameter? I'll do that and see what happens - but no, I don't have any htaccess files in any subdirectories.

Comment: In my IIS installation, I actually DO have nested htaccess files and they seem to work appropriately.

Comment: I also do not have any nested htaccess files in this deployment. Neither above, nor below the directory in question.

Comment: do you have something else in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.* index.php
```

This is a wild guess. You should enable logging and post the logs if we are to provide more than guesses, because the surface of the things that can go wrong is big ;)

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log                                                                                                                                                                      
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

Comment: Wild guesses are not really a good idea. Please read the Apache documentation, which states that `REQUEST_FILENAME` is "the full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request." It already contains the document root, which is why nobody ever uses it the way you have in your answer.

Comment: If you actually [read](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) the documentation, it says otherwise (scroll down to the `REQUEST_FILENAME`- it has 3 sentences and somehow nobody seems to read past the first one...). So, what really is not a good idea, is attacking people who do carefully read the docs instead of relying on copy/pasted code from what others use. Some of those others may actually know exactly what they're using and why it is right to do so for their specific setup. It's not by chance that RTFM is as old as computers. @MikeRockett

Comment: Okay, I apologise - but no need for you to be rude. I was not *attacking* you - merely stated the facts as I had them at the time. Plus, mentioning *wild guesses* in your answer doesn't help.

Comment: Based on the OP's unusual issue and lack of detailed info, other that suggesting him to go through the logs (which both you and I did in our posts), there's not much else to do. In that context, I find it fair to suggest an edge case. I labeled it as a `wild guess` because it is (given the context), but if there's a small chance that it may be helpful, I don't see why not mention it. Tbh, I found your comment offensive when I saw it, but if I misread your intention, I apologize for the touch of harshness in my response.

Comment: Well understood. (No hard feelings 'ey.)

Comment: On Windows hosts (ex. running XAMPP during devel) I have noticed that %{REQUEST_FILENAME} will not contain the full path. In this case the solution above will help.

Perhaps it helps someone, my htaccess rule is:

RewriteEngine on

LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace4 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NS]

Answer (score 3):

You can try this alternative check for files/directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In normal circumstances `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` resolves to same full filesystem path as `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` but in your case `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is not getting resolved.

Comment: A fair guess - I'll give this a spin.

Comment: I would appreciate to know the reason of downvote here.

Comment: Might be case of 'strategical downvoting'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `404 Error` way to redirect users to `index` if file/page doesn't exists.

As it follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: @MikeRockett Explain why it souldn't ?

Comment: Because, as @anubhava said, `ErrorDocument` and `RewriteCond` have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @MikeRockett It works as expeted for me, have you tested?

Comment: `RewriteCond` is for `RewriteRule`. The use of `ErrorDocument` has got nothing to do with `RewriteCond` - it is a standalone statement. Removing the two conditions will not make any difference to the result.

Comment: @MikeRockett Oh! Now I understood. Well then should I remove it ? As it doesn't affect the `ErrorDocument` ?

Comment: Correct. But the use of `ErrorDocument` does not resolve the OP's problem.

Comment: @MikeRockett And why doesn't it resolves OP's problem? He wants to redirect to `index` when `file` or `page` doesn't exists, right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it doesn't answer the question, which asks *why* the code is not doing what it is expected to be doing when all given indicators say that it should work.

Comment: if file dos not exist you need the server to return 404 and this is not normal to have 404 and not 404 content in it

Comment: @Macerier but the user wants to redirect to `index` when `"404"` error is invoked.

Comment: @holpducki the code the OP has should work in normal conditions. Do you think is normal to trow 404 if you handle the links by php script? 404 should be town by script in the request has no answer. Your idea works (i used this in an project) but my problem is about the way it is solved because OP wants to handle requests not errors.

Comment: @Macerier If user enters `www.opswebsite.com/somefilethatdonotexists.php` it will throw a 404 error, which it doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

This is very unusual, and it is obviously not the intended result. As such, it is safe to assume that the issue could be that another `.htaccess` file is interfering with your rewrites. Alternatively, you could have a directive in another Apache configuration file that is doing this.

In order to trace the root cause of the problem at hand, you'll need to tell Apache to log/trace rewrites. As you are running Apache 2.4, you need to set your `LogLevel` for your virtual host, like so:

```bsh
LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace4 # where trace<n> is the level of tracing
```

*<sub>(Side note: Previous versions of Apache made use of `RewriteLog`, but this is now deprecated in the latest Apache 2.4.)</sub>*

Then, you can go into your site's logs, and somewhere you should see the following:

```bsh
[Tue Jun 16 16:51:40.123993 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 5412:tid 1680] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client <client_ip_port>] <ip> - - [<your_domain>/sid#1406168][rid#1cb2150/initial] [perdir <document_root>] RewriteCond: input='<document_root>' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Tue Jun 16 16:51:40.123993 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 5412:tid 1680] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client <client_ip_port>] <ip> - - [<your_domain>/sid#1406168][rid#1cb2150/initial] [perdir <document_root>] RewriteCond: input='<document_root>' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
```

If you don't see those lines (specifically the first line), then it could mean that the file indeed does not exist. If the line is present, then I'm afraid something else is causing the problem. Nonetheless, using the tracer will help you identify the issue, so that you may perhaps resolve it easily.

Comment: I presume that this is another htaccess directive? I'll implement it today and see what I come up with,.]

Comment: This doesn't go in your `.htaccess` file. You need to place this in `httpd.conf` or your virtual host configuration for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is because you catch everything and sent it to index.php in RewriteRule try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteBase` is not needed when you use absolute paths in target URI like `/index.php`